# How to update the yii CGridview summary after deleting a row

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

Deletion is happening using ajax, but the count summary showing like (1-25 of 100 ) has to be updated as (1-25 of 99). how to do that?

UPDATED THE CODE:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$provider,
            'filter' => $model,
            'hideHeader'=>false,
          'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,data){jQuery("#summaryUpdate").html(" - " +jQuery(".grid-view .summary").html());}',
            'columns'=>array(
                'id',
                'username',
                'dob',
                'email',
                array(
                    'class'=>'CCustomColumn',
                    'afterDelete' => 'function(id,data){jQuery("#summaryUpdate").html(" - " +jQuery(".grid-view .summary").html());}',

                    'updateButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/edit.png',
                    'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/delete.png',
                    'buttons'=>array(
                    'update'=>array('url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("user/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', ),
                    'delete'=>array('url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("user/delete", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', )
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/css/gridview.css",
        ));
```

Comment: this is the default behavior (i.e deletion by ajax and update of summary), so it should work automatically, can you show your gridview, and how you are deleting by ajax?

Comment: Please check the code. Now the update summary is not happening automatically.

Comment: CCustomColumn is subclassed from CButtonColumn?, which functions are you overriding in it? do you absolutely need it? asking that because everything that you are doing in the column looks like you can already do it with CButtonColumn. Also do you have a custom summary somewhere other than within the gridview div? i'm guessing summaryUpdate is the summary div?

Comment: yes, i am having a span tag for the summary to display on the top of the grid `<span class="summary" id="summaryUpdate"></span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should update the summary automatically 
did you use

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('grid-name');
```

to update the grid ?